# Running watchdog file system watch within pyqt

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, watchdog

I have a pyqt widget that allows a user to make some setting and then save them to a sqlite database, this settings affect watchdog which uses the following code to check changes to the file system

```
 try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
```

The above cannot be placed in the qwidget app code as it will stop some of pyqt code from ever being executed  i had tried :

```
 """ Some other code """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = vdrive()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("app.xpm"), ex)
    trayIcon.show()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How would i integrate watchdog with pyqt to watch the file system changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `watchdog.observers.Observer` inherits from `threading.Thread`, so the actual checking is done in a thread that you start when you call `observer.start()`.

The loop doesn't do anything except letting the program run until the user interrupts it. You can remove it completely and run the Qt event loop as usual:

```
observer.start()
status = app.exec_()
observer.stop()
observer.join()
sys.exit(status)
```